# Angular - Type 'IUser | null' is not assignable to type 'IUser'

Tags: angular

In my Angular-13, I have this code:

```
export class AuthService {
  baseUrl = environment.apiUrl;
  private currentUserSource = new ReplaySubject<IUser | null>(1);
  currentUser$ = this.currentUserSource.asObservable();

...
}

export class JwtInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private authService: AuthService) {}

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<unknown>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<unknown>> 
 {
    let currentUser: IUser;
    this.authService.currentUser$.pipe(take(1)).subscribe(user => currentUser = user);
    if(currentUser!){
      request = request.clone({
        setHeaders:{
          Authorization: `Bearer ${currentUser.token}`
        }
      });
    }
    return next.handle(request);
  }
}
```

I got this error:

> Type 'IUser | null' is not assignable to type 'IUser'

currentUser is highlighted in user => currentUser = user)

How do I resolve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the type of your variable `currentUser` is `IUser` and it is been assined the value from `currentUser$`, which I believe has the type `Observable<IUser | null>`

To fix it replace line

```
let currentUser: IUser;
```

with

```
let currentUser: IUser | null;
```

or make sure the type of  `currentUser$` is `Observable<IUser>`